# Почему не выводит картинки из папки php+mysql?

Tags: php, html, mysql

использую аналог этого кода https://codewithawa.com/posts/image-...mysql-database 
пытаюсь сделать загрузку и вывод картинки из бд на страницу... Дает выбирать , ЗАГРУЖАЕТ в дб, но обратно выдает картинку и показывает что она типа сломана, а сам текст который вписываешь - выводит . Уже третий день  не могу понять в чем ошибка... думаю что где то после цикла , в строчке где вывод картинки, но вроде же там всё правильно...Заранее спасибо

```
    <?php
      // Create database connection
      $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "image_upload");

      // Initialize message variable
      $msg = "";

      // If upload button is clicked ...
      if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
        // Get image name
        $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        // Get text
        $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);

        // image file directory
        $target = "images/"."image_upload($image)";

        $sql = "INSERT INTO images (image, image_text) VALUES ('$image', 
    '$image_text')";
    // execute query
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);

        if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
          $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
        }else{
          $msg = "Failed to upload image";
        }
      }
      $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Image Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="content">
  <?php
    while (($row=$result->fetch_assoc())!=false) {
      echo '<div id="img_div">
       <img src="images/'.$row["image"].'" >
         <p>'.$row['image_text'].'</p>
       </div>';
    }
  ?>
  <form method="POST" action="kartinka.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="size" value="1000000">
    <div>
      <input type="file" name="image">
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea 
        id="text" 
        cols="40" 
        rows="4" 
        name="image_text" 
        placeholder="Say something about this image..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button type="submit" name="upload">POST</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `$target = "images/"."image_upload($image)";` что в директории images? У вас файл с названием `image_upload($image)` ? если так то ссылаетесь вы на просто $image. Если нет, то это функция и должно быть `$target = "images/".image_upload($image);`

Comment: спасибо за ответ. только что самому вот секунду в секунду дошло   $target = "images/"."$image"; так поставил и пошло...только вы не знаете ,почему после обновления страницы записи копируются и выводятся еще раз? тип добавил запись - обновил и она второй раз появляется...

Comment: Для начала переменную не нужно оборачивать в кавычки. А так по f5 данные формы отправляются повторно, поэтому нужно после загрузки делать переход а не продолжать скрипт.

Comment: понял , спасибо больше ... я не знаю есть ли здесь или нет кнопка "лучший ответ"...только зарегался здесь .

Comment: В этой переписке нет, только стрелка вверх есть, но у вас возможно нет. А так если пишут полноценный ответ, то появляется галочка ответ на вопрос. Удачи.